# extract-text-webpack-plugin to output css from scss in new folder in output

Tags: css, webpack

I can't seem to make extract-text-webpack-plugin generate the css from scss in a special folder in output.  I know that there is a publicPath option but it doesn't seem to do anything.  The css is still generated along with the other css's in my output folder.
can anyone help?

in my config:

```
test: /(add-to-home\.scss)$/,
loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style","css!postcss!sass", {publicPath: "output/a/b"})
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

To output the your style.css file in "output/a/b"

You need to use the ExtractTextPlugin

```
{
    test: /(\.scss|\.css)$/,
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?postcss!sass'),
}
```

In the plugin section use :

```
 plugins: [
  new ExtractTextPlugin('output/a/b/style.css', {allChunks: true})

 ],
```

This will output the extracted css in the output/a/b/ folder.

Comment: The problem when I do this is that all css's are generated in a/b/ but I only want one of them there.  I still want the rest of the css's (from other scss's) to be generated as usual in output.

Comment: maybe you can't try: 
test: /(add-to-home\.scss)$/,
loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style","'css?postcss!sass?name=output/a/b/style.css'")